# Generate complex signal with sinusoidal phase

Tags: signal-analysis, phase, signal-synthesis

I would like to syntethically generate a range of complex numbers whose phase (argument) over `t` will form a clean sine wave of frequency `f` and amplitude `A`. I can't seem to wrap my head around how to approach this. Thank you for any advice or hint!

Comment: First step is to write down the equation that describes the numbers you want to calculate. Can you do that?

Comment: well, sorta... I know that the phase of a complex number is calculated by taking the `atan2` function (and unwrapping any jumps between consecutive arguments $$\geq\pi$$ radians). And I know the general 'sine' or wave function follows $$Ae^{j\omega{}t}$$ but somehow I fail to connect the dots for inverting the process...

Comment: That is correct, and you've got the amplitude and the frequency. Now, what is the range of time you're interested in?

Comment: Ideally I'd like to generate three full cycles, so `0...3T`

Comment: OK, you seem to have all you need then. What is the difficulty? If the issue is purely programming, you're better off asking this question on stackoverfow or some other programming Q&A site.

Comment: jup, I've got it now. Thanks for lifting me onto the solution, I really needed this @MBaz
here's a solution in python for anyone who stumbles upon this:
`A = 1
f = 0.2 #hz
T = 1/f
w = 2*np.pi / T
t = np.linspace(0, 3*T, 160)
y = A*np.exp(1j*w*t)
re = np.real(y)
z = np.cos(re) + 1j*np.sin(re)
plt.plot(np.unwrap(np.angle(z)))`